# Best way to include jQuery into TYPO3 backend

Tags: jquery, typo3, backend

I've read, what jQuery use could provoke some conflicts in TYPO3 backend. But in the same time, ExtJS proposes jQuery adapter to use these 2 frameworks together.

What will be the most safe, efficient and transparent way to include jQuery and it's plugins into TYPO3 Backend (4.5,4.6,4.7) ? If there are already some extensions, which realizes it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've contacted Jürgen Furrer, the author of T3 jQuery. He adviced to use the following method using his extension :

```
if (t3lib_extMgm::isLoaded('t3jquery')) {
    require_once(t3lib_extMgm::extPath('t3jquery').'class.tx_t3jquery.php');
    $path_to_lib = tx_t3jquery::getJqJSBE();
    $script_to_lib = tx_t3jquery::getJqJSBE(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is safer in terms of knowing which version of JQuery you are using. So in a template you would add:

```
page.includeJS {
    file1 = fileadmin/templates/project1/js/app.js 
}
```